# How do I solve the loop issues? It is the place of the brackets but I cannot figure out where they should be placed

Tags: java

I am trying to code Rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock. My code is attached and the loops keep repeating. I believe the curly braces are placed wrong but I cannot figure out where without getting an error message.

```
public class RockPaperScissors_v2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //scanner
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        //randomizer for comp
        Random rand = new Random();

        //variables
        int rock = 1;
        int paper = 2;
        int scissors = 3;
        int lizard = 4;
        int spock = 5;
        int round;
        int choice;
        int compChoice = 1;
        int countOfWins = 0;
        int countOfLosses = 0;
        int countOfTies = 0;

        //ask how many rounds to play; max 10 --> if more than 10, print error message and quit.
        do {
            System.out.println("How many rounds do you want to play?");
            //output
            round = inputReader.nextInt();
            if (round < 1 || round > 10) {
                System.out.println("Error Message: Please type a number between 1 and 10.");
                return;
            }
        } while (round != 0);

        System.out.println("Please select a number from the follow:");
        System.out.println("1) Rock"
                + "\n 2) Paper"
                + "\n 3) Scissors"
                + "\n 4) Lizard"
                + "\n 5) Spock");

        compChoice = rand.nextInt(5 - 2 + 2) + 1;

        choice = inputReader.nextInt();
        //if statements for all scenarios
        if (compChoice == 1) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Tie game.");
                countOfTies++;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Rock gets covered by paper. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes lizard. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                System.out.println("Spock vaporizes rock. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            }
        } else if (compChoice == 2) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Paper covers rock. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Tie game.");
                countOfTies++;
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Lizard eats paper. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                System.out.println("Paper disproves Spock. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            }
        } else if (compChoice == 3) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Tie game.");
                countOfTies++;
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Scissors decapitates lizard. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                System.out.println("Spock smashes scissors. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            }
        } else if (compChoice == 4) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes lizard. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Lizard eats paper. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Scissors decapitates lizard. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Tie game.");
                countOfTies++;
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                System.out.println("Lizard poisons Spock. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            }
        } else if (compChoice == 5) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Rock crushes lizard. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Lizard eats paper. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Scissors decapitates lizard. You lose.");
                countOfLosses++;
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Lizard poisons Spock. You win!");
                countOfWins++;
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                System.out.println("Tie game.");
                countOfTies++;
            }
        }

        //print out wins, losses, and ties
        System.out.println("Number of Wins:" + countOfWins);
        System.out.println("Number of Losses: " + countOfLosses);
        System.out.println("Number of Ties: " + countOfTies);

        //ask user if wants to play again
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again (Y/N)?");
        String playAgain = inputReader.next();
        if (playAgain.equals("Y")) {
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of curly braces... Try making methods and a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

With `while (round != 0);` the loop will exit only when you are inserting `0`, which seems to be wrong and also will never happen since in that case you are closing the program with `return`.

I suggest to remove the `return` and to change the `while` condition with `while (round < 1 || round > 10);`, which will terminate the loop only when a value between `1` and `10` is inserted.